# JPA CriteriaAPI: correct usage of isMember()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I am using JPAs criteria api to request some objects form my database and apply filter to the request.

the following code shows the method that assambles and executes the query:

```
@Override
    public List<MyClass> findAll(MyClassFilterObject filter) {
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = this.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<MyClass> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MyClass);

        Root<MyClass> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyClass);
        List<Predicate> criteriaList = new LinkedList<Predicate>();
        if (!filter.getMyClassStatus().equals("")) {
            Path<String> statusPath = root.get("MyClassStatus");
            criteriaList.add(builder.equal(statusPath, MyClassStatus.valueOf(filter.getMyClassStatus())));
        }
        if (!filter.getMyClassType().equals("")) {
            Expression<Set<MyClassType>> MyClassTypesQuery = root.get("MyClassType");
            criteriaList.add(builder.isMember(MyClassType.valueOf(filter.getMyClassType()), MyClassTypesQuery));
        }
        if (criteriaList.size()>0){
            criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[criteriaList.size()])));
        }
        TypedQuery<MyClass> typedQuery = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(filter.getPagenumber() * 10);
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(10);
        List<MyClass> MyClasss = typedQuery.getResultList();

        if (MyClasss.isEmpty()) {
            return new LinkedList<MyClass>();
        }

        return MyClasss;
    }
```

this code always returns the same two objects, no matter what i choose as "MyClassType".
MyClass has a set of MyClassType (an Enum value) objects attached and i want to know if the MyClassType object from my filter is a member of this collection

I am not sure if i am using the isMember method right

Comment: and the sql executed in the datastore is ?

Comment: the query that gets assembled by hibernate in the JPQL-query looks like this:
select generatedAlias0 from MyClass as generatedAlias0 where :param0 member of generatedAlias0.MyClassType. thats all i can see

Comment: i see no "param0" in the query code above

Comment: The param0 is a MyClassType and is filled with the correct value from the filter